# Efficient way to remove duplicates in [AnyObject] Swift

Tags: objective-c, swift

I have a swift array of [AnyObject]. Some objects have the same `RestaurantName`. What is the optimal (least resource intense) way to remove duplicates and keep the one with the highest `Votes`

Note: only the `objectId` is the same in `RestaurantName`, there is still a unique id associated with each.

#### Array of AnyObject

```
Optional([<FoodPhoto: 0x1741088b0, objectId: FNJjZHxOvg, localId: (null)> {
    PhotoName = Test1;
    PhotoUploaded = "<PFFile: 0x170460b00>";
    RestaurantName = "<Restaurant: 0x17010a4d0, objectId: 0aKFrpKN46>";
    UserUploaded = "<PFUser: 0x1703627c0, objectId: wNJPsJDV6t>";
    Votes = 2;
}, <FoodPhoto: 0x17410ab90, objectId: yhiMZ3dkHR, localId: (null)> {
    PhotoName = Title1;
    PhotoUploaded = "<PFFile: 0x170460c00>";
    RestaurantName = "<Restaurant: 0x17010a7a0, objectId: 0aKFrpKN46>";
    UserUploaded = "<PFUser: 0x170362580, objectId: Zk56DgHGhi>";
    Votes = 5;
}, <FoodPhoto: 0x17410ab00, objectId: UNTRadeMjg, localId: (null)> {
    PhotoName = title2;
    PhotoUploaded = "<PFFile: 0x170460cc0>";
    RestaurantName = "<Restaurant: 0x17010a8c0, objectId: 0aKFrpKN46>";
    UserUploaded = "<PFUser: 0x170362340, objectId: Zk56DgHGhi>";
    Votes = 0;
}, <FoodPhoto: 0x17410ac20, objectId: 7C8voifUHd, localId: (null)> {
    PhotoName = title3;
    PhotoUploaded = "<PFFile: 0x170460d80>";
    RestaurantName = "<Restaurant: 0x17010a9e0, objectId: 0aKFrpKN46>";
    UserUploaded = "<PFUser: 0x1703624c0, objectId: Zk56DgHGhi>";
    Votes = 0;
}])
```

Answer (score 2):

If order is not important, what I'd do is create a hashmap key'd by your objectId as follows:

```
var hashtable = [String: FoodPhoto]()
for foodPhoto in photos {
    let oldFoodPhoto = hashtable[foodPhoto.objectId]
    if oldFoodPhoto == nil || oldFoodPhoto!.Votes < foodPhoto.Votes {
        hashtable[foodPhoto.objectId] = foodPhoto
    }
}
```

Then hashtable.values will have all the unique FoodPhoto(s).